# JavaScript fetch() - mapping array of ReadableStreams to array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I have an array of Promises returned from a batch of `fetch()` calls:

`const fetchResults = [Promise, Promise, Promise]`

The `.body` of each `Promise` is [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams), converting which to string appears to be an annoyingly verbose async operation. I'm attempting to use await to read the body string and map it back to the array:

```
profileHTMLDocs.map(async (doc) => { 
    doc.text()
        .then(async (html) => { return await html; }) 
})
```

I've tried a few variations but it still seems to return an array of promises instead of array of html strings. What am I missing? Is it because the implicit return is `doc.text()`?

Comment: That's... not how `async/await` should be used. you want to `await` a function that's been marked as `async`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wanna use Promise.all to turn the array of promises into a promise resolving to an array of strings:

```
const result = Promise.all(fetchResults.map(p => p.then(res => res.text())));
```

Comment: And in this code, `result` will be a Promise. You could use `const result = await Promise.all(...);` if you just want the value that results.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that.